# Android Studio - change selected cardview background color changing more than one

Tags: android

I'm trying that when a user clicks on a cardview, to not be selected twice, set that cardview visibility to GONE.

The problem is that when I click on a cardview and go down on my recycler other cardviews were set to GONE to.

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            iOnClickPerkCrearBtnListener.onClickBtnListener(perksGlobalesResponse.get(getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()));

                txtPerk1.setText(perksGlobalesResponse.get(getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()).getIdPerk() + "");
                p1 = (perksGlobalesResponse.get(getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()).getIdPerk() + "");
                CrearPerksSurvisFragment.perk1Txt.setText(p1);
                n1 = (perksGlobalesResponse.get(getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()).getNombre() + "");

                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

Comment: Share the code of your recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to show more of your adapters code, but my guess is you are setting the view holder to GONE, since android RecyclerView's re-use viewholders this makes all the viewholders set to GONE when you scroll.

What you need to do is have a "visible" variable on whatever itemModel you're using in your adapter and then in onBindViewHolder set the visibility of the ViewHolder based on the visible varible of the itemModel

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You have to set visibility gone only for `CardView` of that particular position of `recyclerView`.

Comment: Yes... but how?